# How to find xpath of text with 2 words separated by br tag

Tags: selenium, xpath

Above is sort of question interviewer asked me. He asked to write down the xpath.

I answered you can use `contains()` with `AND` operator. I also answered you can use `following::` but he said that's not correct answer.

Does anyone have an idea how to find xpath of entire statement where line break tag is used in it?

Comment: Anyone who asks for "the XPath" is clearly starting from a position of some ignorance, because (a) there will always be an infinite number of solutions, and (b) well-informed people call it "an XPath expression", not "an XPath". But dealing with ignorant interviewers is of course one of the skills you have to acquire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disregard an intervening `br` element by testing the string value of the parent element.

For example, for XML containing such `div` elements,

```
<div>
  <input id='2'/>
  Hello
  <br/>
  World
</div>
```

this XPath,

```
//div[normalize-space() = "Hello World"]
```

will select all such `div` elements whose space-normalized string value is `"Hello World"`.

---

OTOH, you can specifically select elements containing `Hello<br/>World` via this XPath:

```
//br[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text()[normalize-space()="Hello"]]]
    [following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()[normalize-space()="World"]]]/..
```

which is just a rewrite of [Mads Hansen's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49724874/290085) (+1), so please upvote his answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Tried with normalize-space() and it worked pretty well!

Answer (score 1):

If the fact that the `<br/>` is separating the two words is significant, then the following XPath would work. It looks for `foo<br/>bar`

It selects any element that contains a child `text()` node with the value `foo` that is immediately followed by a `<br/>` sibling, which is immediately followed by a sibling `text()` node with the value `bar`.

Not knowing how exacting you want to be. You could accommodate leading and trailing whitespace characters by using `normalize-space()` when evaluating the `text()` values:

```
//*[text()[normalize-space(.)='foo']       
  /following-sibling::node()[1][self::br]         
    /following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()[ normalize-space(.)='bar']]]
```